# Creating/Importing many bitmaps to use for maptiles stack memory issues

Tags: android, bitmap

I'm pretty new to Android, but I wanted to try and make a tile based game, where you would move around a map, square by square.

However I'm having problems with opening many resources, for now i'm just using the same image for each tile (but in future this will obviously change)

The problem is when creating a decently sized map this code:

```
mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new BufferedInputStream(res.openRawResource(R.drawable.tile)));
mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmap.getWidth(), mBitmap.getHeight());
canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, mX, mY, null);
```

is causing an error when emulated...

I understand that emulators/phones have limited memory, but I thought they would have enough to hold say 20x20 tiles?

-I was hoping to have much bigger maps, but the only workaround I could think of is destroying tiles once they are out of view and drawing new ones as they come into view (as you move)

I've tried to do that here:

```
if (tile.mX > 100 && tile.mX < 600){
   tile.mBitmap = null;
} else {
   //draw it with code above
}
```

So the code above would loop through each tile in a array (every frame) and only draw the ones within a certain X co-ordinates.

I was just wondering if this was the 'way' to do it? -opening and nulling bitmaps whenever you move? Or is there is simpler way? Have I missed a command which would destroy the bitmap better than null which would make my program more efficient?

The programs runs EXTREMELY slow on the emulator, is this a problem? -Or is it safe to assume loading many bitmaps each frame would be slow on an emulator? Will it still run slow on phone devices?

Any tips/help would be great, thanks!

Comment: For the speed issues, if you're not running Intel Atom system images already, switch to them instead.

Comment: It's a 3kb .png, what should I be using?

Comment: Oh, I mean that switch to Intel Atom system image emulator. It's much faster and more fluent to use compared to Google provided ARM ones.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you must load/free the bitmaps every time. I also wrote a program that's handling a lot of (large) bitmaps and we had lots of memory problems until I stumbled on the [LruCache](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html) class provided by the Android API (the linked JavaDoc even has an example on how to use it for bitmaps). LRU stands for Least Recently Used, so basically it keeps elements used shortly and removes elements not used for a long time.

So what you should do is this: You'll paint your playfield using a `SurfaceView` - this means you'll have to paint it every time the `draw` method is called. So when drawing, you'll have to know which tiles are visible and you just paint those tiles. For every tile you look up the LruCache to see if you've loaded that bitmap already and if so, simply paint it on the correct position of the surface view. If the bitmap is not in the cache you load it, put it into the cache and paint it onto the surface.